# python 2.6 vs 2.7, for pylons/pyramid projects

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid

What problems can I have if I will use python 2.7 instead python 2.6 for my pylons/pyramid projects? Before I use python 2.6 on my ubuntu 10.04 but now I have ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop with python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Ubuntu the package manager will fix most of the minor issues such as finding the packages you used to have in 2.6.
But there are some Packages that isn't compliant with Python2.7.

Mainly Python2.7 is a backwards compatible version from 3.X, or at least Python 2.7 was an upgrade from 2.6 towards the 3.X syntax and all it's new functions while the translation to 3.X was made.

Here's some info:

- http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html
- http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.7/

Mainly Python2.7 should just give you more functions but can cause unexpected problems,
Go ahead and upgrade it on a seperate machine, run your code, if it works, upgrade your real machine to Python2.7.

The problems that might occur are minor, you should be able to fix them within 1h.

Comment: There really shouldn't be any problems.  If you happen to find some, please report them on the pyramid bug tracker.

Comment: Perhaps not with Pyramid per say but Python might encounter some errors on the side. Such as iterations and how you process class items etc, i can't remember the problems i encoutered but i know there was a few minor ones.

Answer (score 1):

[According to this post](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.2/narr/install.html), Pyramid 1.2 (as is 1.1) is fully supported on Python 2.5.x, 2.6.x, and 2.7.x so you should be all set.  From my own personal experience,I haven't run into any issues with Pyramid/Python2.7.

These days my Pyramid stack consists of:

- python 2.7
- khufu
- sqlalchemy 0.7.x

and it works quite well.

Comment: All pyramid tests are run automatically against python 2.6, python 2.7, Jython and PyPy, guaranteeing that Pyramid will work on those platforms. Note that python 2.5 is not in that list, so while it may work it is not verified normally.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html`
You'll find what all you'll ever need to know.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case the pyramid stack is mostly too large for each person to have to go and inspect if python 2.7 will break anything based on the whatsnew url.  Fortunately the pyramid team has done that for us.